# OpenCV on CodeBlocks under limux mint seems not to find library

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks, linux-mint

OpenCV 4.5.4, CodeBlocks 20.03 mint 20.02
I took a test code like this:

```
#define HAVE_OPENCV_HIGHGUI
#define HAVE_OPENCV_IMGCODECS
#include <opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat img = imread("arnold_schwarzenegger.jpg");
    if(img.empty())
       return -1;
    namedWindow("arnold_schwarzenegger", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("arnold_schwarzenegger", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles ok, but it doesn't produce the required actions, in fact, it does nothing.
When in debugger, it shows a message:
In __cxa_throw () (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
#5  0x00005555555553d4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe668) at /home/mikhail/CodeBlocksProjects/TryOpenCVALinux/main.cpp:11
/home/mikhail/CodeBlocksProjects/TryOpenCVALinux/main.cpp:11:225:beg:0x5555555553d4
11      namedWindow("arnold_schwarzenegger", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
At /home/mikhail/CodeBlocksProjects/TryOpenCVALinux/main.cpp:11

I do no t understand what it wants to say and I could not find where to look it up.
Could anybody help me decipher the message or indicate where it is described?
Thanks.

Comment: 1. NEVER redefine HAVE_XXX macros in *your code* 2. `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` is the correct way, 3. it's `linux`, not `limux` -- you're a sloppy person ;)

Comment: berak, I regret you started answering before reading the question.

Comment: *precisely* how do you compile and link your program? "it does nothing" tells me you're not linking required libraries or linking wrong versions of them, or there's a conflict between a library you link and one that's linked by opencv libraries already, or you mix debug and release build code

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/seems-not-to-find-the-implementation/6824

Comment: Christoph, the thing is that I have both files, libopencv_imcodec.co.4.5.4, which contains the imread implementation, and libopencv_highgui.so.4.5.4, which contains the namedWindow implementation in the same directory, usr->local->lib, and I pass both to the linker, as well as libopencv_core.so.4.5.4. Nevertheless, the imread passes while namedWindow, as well as any other highgui function I tried, does not. As for the version, I am brand new linux user and I have never had any other version installed. As for compilation, I tried it in CodeBlocks and in the terminal with the same result.

Comment: I beg your pardon, I spoke about libopencv_imcodec.so.4.5.4, not co.4.5.4.

Comment: I remind that the question was how to understand the debugger message.